# Unexpected character in SoapUi

Tags: json, rest, soapui, endpoint, ready-api

In my project in soapui I'm testing and getting a mistake. Can anyone help me where the problem is? I read data from database and I'm putting in offerID.

My request

```
{
 "offerID": ${offers_pm5#OFFERS_PM},
 "participation": 0.9,
 "description": "test",
 "premiumFrequency": "12",
 "technicalPackageSymbol": "test",
 "marketingPackageSymbol": null
}
```

My Response:

```
<data contentType="text/plain" contentLength="211"><![CDATA[Unexpected character (',' (code 44)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
at [Source: io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletInputStreamImpl@3e93433b; line: 2, column: 14]]]></data>
```

My sql code:

```
SELECT OFFERS.OF_OFFER.PM AS OFFERS_PM
 FROM OFFERS.OF_OFFER
 WHERE ROWNUM=1
```

Comment: it looks like your # causes problem (I would say that from the syntactic color), in SOAPUI '#' are used in ${#myProperty} form. I guess OFFERS_PM is a property to interpret, have you tried writing ${offers_pm5${OFFERS_PM}} ? though I'm not sure at all this could work ...

Comment: What do you see in raw request? Is the value changed to actual in place of property expansion?